# How to handle many columns / variable schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, reporting-services, database-schema

I apologize in advance in case this question has been asked already.

I'm working on revamping a reporting application used within my company. The requirements are:

- Support addition of new fields (done through web app) and allow users to select those fields when building reports. Currently there are 300 of these, and right now their values are stored in a single SQL Server table with 300 columns. Users have to be able to select these new fields in report builder. In other words, the schema is dynamic.
- Improve report generation performance.

My thought process was to split up these 300 (and potentially more) columns into multiple tables (normalization), but I'm not sure that's the right approach given there doesn't seem to be a logical way of grouping data without ending up with 20+ tables.

Another option would be to store values in rows (key, attribute, attribute-value) then do a pivot, but I'm not sure that would perform well. This option would handle the dynamic schema nicely, but the pivot statements would have to be built programmatically before a user can consume data (views).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to __target specific programming problems__ - "ideal approaches" may easily be too broad. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. Please take a __[tour]__.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll remove the open-ended questions and just stick with the 2 options I'm considering.

Comment: Good idea. By the way, that was an auto comment.